# Libgdx Quiz- Using SQLite Database?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I have been learning Android development and using the Libgdx framework for over a month now and want to create a test app. The app i want to create is a quiz and im stuck on the situation on how i am going to store all the questions, answers.

Being a web developer for many years i of course thought of a database but libgdx doesn't have much support for sqlite which leaves me stuck on how to achieve the storing without using a database.

Does anyway know any way to use sqlite with libgdx or how i can achieve this another way, i would appreciate the help, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would not go with SQLite in this case. Since it is just a test app and you probably won't have millions of questions and won't need to do any kind of querying, I'd suggest you to use JSON to store your questions.

The [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) support of LibGDX is pretty good and it works on all platforms as well. Have a look at the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON) to see some examples of how to use it.

Furthermore it means that you can easily edit your questions, since it is a human readable file format.

Comment: Well i want to eventually build it into a large quiz with hundreds of questions which is why i thought a database would be the best way to go for testing so i would already know how to do it when it comes to creating a full version of the app.

Comment: JSON is actually a pretty efficient file format. I think "hundreds" of questions shouldn't be a problem.