# Implementing Database in libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a small libgdx game. I want to create sqlite database for storing game scores. 
But i am not able to do the  same as that i used in the activity. How to implement the same

Thanks in advance

Comment: Suggestion, Game Score is small information, You should store it in SharedPreference. No need to code for Sqlite.

Comment: A database to store scores? Isn't that a bit overpowered? I'd advise you to store this via JSON, XML or maybe even `Preferences`... Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22518300/libgdx-quiz-using-sqlite-database?rq=1

Comment: Can you please suggest a tutorial for the same @noone

Comment: `Preferences`: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences

`Json`: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-%26-writing-JSON
`XMLReader` (API): http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlReader.html

`XMLWriter` (API): http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/XmlWriter.html

Comment: @noone but i need to store the values permanently in the game

Comment: @varghesekutty Yes, all those options are permanently stored as files.

Answer (score 1):

Using a Database just to store scores seems to be a bit overpowered. Furthermore it won't be cross-platform compatible anymore, which is one of the major advantages with LibGDX.

I'd suggest you to do this either via:

- an XML file: [LibGDX: XML](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-xml)
- a JSON file: [LibGDX: JSON](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Reading-&-writing-JSON)
- `Preferences`: [Preferences](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Preferences)

With `Preferences` you would just store something like "level"="score".
With XML or JSON you could do much more, e. g. have a little class like the following:

```
public class Highscore {

    private String username;
    private String level;
    private int score;

}
```

And then you would just write an array of those to JSON/XML and read it in as an array the next time you start the app. For a limited amount of highscores, this should be implemented pretty quickly and should not be a performance issue. Just load the list once on startup, and only update it when you detect a new highscore.